# ETW providers for devenv.exe and msbuild.exe

Tags: etw

Are there ETW providers for the Visual Studio development environment and the Microsoft build process?

Comment: I can't see any usermode providers for devenv.exe when I run **xperf -providers**. Why do you need this?

Comment: You can dump a list of providers in DevEnv.exe by **logman query providers -pid <pid of devenv.exe>**. But they are not necessary from Visual Studio as they can be from DLL libraries that DevEnv.exe uses.

Comment: I would like to trace performance events from when a user selects F5 until a breakpoint. I have a VS extension and I have a build task that I have instrumented with performance tacking events and I'd like to see all these events in the Windows Performance Analyzer tool.

Comment: Where does your build task live? Is it in a custom dll? If so - you can instrument it on its own.